# C++ std::maps and class values with constructors

Tags: c++, stdmap

It's been a long time since I've seen C++ -- 30 years of more, and obviously, things have changed a lot.  I'm also spoiled with Scala, Julia etc, which take care of this magic under the covers, but... no more....  I'm tryihng to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
class Foo {
   uint_fast8_t val1;
   std::string name;
   uint_fast16_t val2;
};

std::map<std::string, Foo> myMap;

myMap["Test"] = { 1, "Test2", 2 };
```

This fails to compile because several operators need to be overloaded for map to work.  Note, this happens evne with a constructor defined such as

```
Foo(uint_fast8_t v1, std::string s, uint_Fast16_t v2) { };
```

If I just do a

```
myMap["Test"] = Foo()
```

This works because the constructor has the expected number of arguments (0) as opposed to 3.  It's probably basic, and I'm sure I'm showing how long it's been, but what did I miss?

Comment: This pretty much has nothing to do with `map`. Classes are not `struct`s, members are private, therefore no default value initialization via list initializer. Checkout [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

All the members of a class are by default private in contrast to struct where all the members are by default public so default value initialization of the member variables in a class via list initializer is **not** allowed.
Kindly refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/) for better understanding.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Failed to understand the relation of initializer_list with object creation by making member public.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class with default constructor,which takes zero arguments.
And you are trying to create he inline object with passing the three arguments.
I will suggest to add the parameterized constructor.

```
class Point { 
private: 
    int x, y; 

public: 
    // Parameterized Constructor 
    Point(int x1, int y1) 
    { 
        x = x1; 
        y = y1; 
    } 

   ...
}; 

// Constructor called 
Point p1(10, 15);
```

Basic C++ constructor types can be checked at [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/)